# ui-router: $stateParams is empty in resolves

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Besides *ui-router*, I am using *ui-bootstrap*'s `$modal` service.

I use `resolve`s (actually passed inside a modal) on the `onEnter` property of the `state` (with url parameters) to activate modals (as mentioned in the [docs|FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state) of ui-router).

I tried to access the `$stateParams`, however it seems to be an **empty object** when the resolves fire.

```
function onEnter($modal, $state) {
  // simple handler
  function transitionToOverlay() {
    return $state.transitionTo('parent');
  }

  // actual modal service 
  $modal
    .open({
      size: 'sm',
      resolve: { getY: getY },
      controller: 'ChildCtrl as child',
      template: template
    })
    .result
    .then(transitionToOverlay)
    .catch(transitionToOverlay);
}

// resolve
function getY($state, $stateParams) {
  console.log('State resolve getY...');
  console.log($stateParams); // returns {} empty object
  return 'y'; // just a dummy resolve
}
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mmYIeoId0RxBLuo6TFGl?p=preview) for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UI-Router doesn't have any control over your $modal call.  Resolves should go on state definitions if you would like UI-Router to inject them.

```
var state = {
  url: '{id}',
  name: 'parent.child',
  resolve: { getY: getYfn }, // moved from $modal call
  onEnter: function(getY) { // injected into onEnter
    $modal.open({
      resolve: { getY: function () { return getY; } }, // passed through to $modal.open
      controller: 'ChildCtrl as child', // ChildCtrl injects getY
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this allows us to ```inject``` the resolve to the controller.

Comment: Thanks. However, how do I access the ```resolve``` if, perhaps, I used ```$modal``` in a ```controller```?

Comment: Nevermind. The resolve seems to contain the response instead of the promise.

Comment: Just like to ask, again. ```resolve: { getY: getY }``` in ```$modal``` doesn't work for me. However, ```resolve: { getY: function() { return getY; } }``` works.

Answer (score 3):

Just posting this in case someone has the same problem...

I had the same problem as in the original question but the selected answer didn't help me too much since I couldn't get to access the resolve defined directly in the state inside my modal controller.

However, I noticed $stateParams is still accessible in the onEnter function so it is possible to create a variable here and then use this variable inside the $modal.open() function.

```
.state('parent.child', {
      url: 'edit/:id',
      // If defining the resolve directly in the state
      /*resolve: { // Here $stateParams.id is defined but I can't access it in the modal controller
          user: function($stateParams) {
            console.log('In state(): ' + $stateParams.id);
            return 'user ' + $stateParams.id;
          }
      },*/
      onEnter: function($modal, $stateParams, $state) {
        var id = $stateParams.id; // Here $stateParams.id is defined so we can create a variable
        $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'modal.html',
          // Defining the resolve in the $modal.open()
          resolve: { 
              user: function($stateParams) {
                console.log('In $modal.open(): ' + $stateParams.id); // Here $stateParams.id is undefined
                console.log(id); // But id is now defined
                return 'user ' + id;
              }
          },
          controller: ChildCtrl,
          controllerAs: 'ctrl'
        })
        .result
        .then(function(result) {
            return $state.go('^');
        }, function(reason) {
            return $state.go('^');
        });
      }
    })
```

Here is an example plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/wMMXDSsXLABFr0P5q2On

Also, if needing to define the resolve function outside the configuration object, we can do it like this:

```
var id = $stateParams.id;
$modal.open({
    resolve: {
        user: myResolveFunction(id)
    },
    ...
});
```

And:

```
function myResolveFunction(id) {
    return ['MyService', function(MyService) {
        console.log('id: ' + id);
        return MyService.get({userId: id});
    }];
}
```